# How to sum cells in a column when respective cell in row matches VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

Having the following sheet “Animals”, how do I get an inventory of number of Birds and Mammals?:

```
|   | A       | B   |  
| - | ------- | --- |  
| 1 | Animal  | Qty |  
| 2 | Chicken | 5   |  
| 3 | Duck    | 2   |  
| 4 | Pig     | 7   |  
| 5 | Horse   | 4   |
```

considering the sheet “Classes” matches each animal to a class:

```
|   | A       | B      |  
| - | ------- | ------ |  
| 1 | Animal  | Class  |  
| 2 | Chicken | Bird   |  
| 3 | Duck    | Bird   |  
| 4 | Pig     | Mammal |  
| 5 | Horse   | Mammal |
```

The sheet “Inventory” would be like this.

What formula I can fill each cell in column B with, that counts the number of animals by class?

```
|   | A      |  B    |  
| - | ------ | ---   |  
|   | Class  | Qty   |  
| 1 | Bird   | =(7)  |  
| 2 | Mammal | =(11) |
```

I thought about SUMIF like in `=SUMIF(Animals!B:B, condition)`, but I cannot seemingly combine VLOOKUP in `condition`, like in `"=VLOOKUP(Animals!A2, Classes!A:B, 2, FALSE)"`. I am not one bit familiar with array formulas, if that is what one would need to do.

I checked [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309525/excel-sum-column-if-condition-is-met-by-checking-other-column-in-same-table#6309681) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204573/sum-values-from-multiple-rows-using-vlookup-or-index-match-functions) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469010/sum-cells-in-a-column-that-have-a-specific-value-in-a-cell-in-their-row), in Stack Overflow and others, but the ones I found, seem to have a condition that checks against specific values instead of a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS($B$2:$B$5,
              VLOOKUP($A$2:$A$5,
                      $A$8:$B$11,
                      2,
                      FALSE),
              A14))
```

The vloopup returns an array `{"bird","bird","mammal","mammal"}` that `SUMIFS()` checks agains to be the class in `A14`.

In this case I laid out the data like this for convenience:

- The first table starts with `aniaml` in `A1`
- The second table starts with `animal` in `A7`
- The last table starts with `class` in `A13`.

Comment: Awesome. I rewrote your formula to use the sheets in my example like this `=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(Animals!$B:$B,VLOOKUP(Animals!$A:$A,Classes!$A:$B,2,FALSE),$A2))` for cell B2 in “Inventory”, and then copy-pasted to B3 letting Google Spreadsheets do the increment. Extra thanks for the explanation of how it works.